# Condition is not verifying the validity of the input

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment that asks a user to input a student name, and then quiz scores until the user chooses to stop. It then calculates the total score and the average of all those scores and outputs them to the screen.

We are moving on to the subject of inheritance and now we are requested to make a class called MonitoredStudent which extends Student. The point of the MonitoredStudent class is to check if the average is above a user inputted average and display whether the student is off academic probation.

I have got most of the program written and when I input just one score (such as 71, when the average I set is 70) it is still displaying that I am on academic probation, even though the one quiz score is above the average I set of 70.

The main issue is that no matter what integer is set for the minimum passing average, I always get a return of false.

I added the "return false" statement in the isOffProbation method as when I add an if-else statement to check if the averageScore (from the Student class) is less than or equal to minPassingAvg eclipse tells me that the method needs a return type of boolean.

```
public class MonitoredStudent extends Student {
    
    int minPassingAvg;
    
    public MonitoredStudent(){
        super();
        minPassingAvg = 0;
    }
    
    public MonitoredStudent(String name, int minPassingAvg) {
        super(name);
        this.minPassingAvg = minPassingAvg;
    }
    
    public int getMinPassingAvg() {
        return minPassingAvg;
    }
    
    public void setMinPassingAvg(int minPassingAvg) {
        this.minPassingAvg = minPassingAvg;
    }
    
    boolean isOffProbation() {
        if(getAverageScore() >= minPassingAvg)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the Student super class:

```
public class Student{

   private String name;

   private double totalScore;

   private int quizCount;
  

   public Student(){  
      name = "";
      totalScore = 0;
      quizCount = 0;
   }


   public Student(String n){  
      name = n;
      totalScore = 0;
      quizCount = 0;
   }


   public void setName(String aName){
      name = aName;
   }
   
   
   public String getName(){  
      return name;
   }


   public void addQuiz(int score){  
      if(score >= 0 && score <= 100){
         totalScore = totalScore + score;
         quizCount = quizCount + 1;
      }else{
         System.out.println("Score must be between 0 and 100, inclusive");
      }
   }


   public double getTotalScore(){  
      return totalScore;
   }

   public double getAverageScore(){  
      return totalScore / quizCount;
   }   
}
```

This is the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonitoredStudentTester{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        MonitoredStudent monStu = new MonitoredStudent();
        String repeat = "n";
        int currentScore = 0;
        int minPassAv;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the student's name:");
        String stuName = scan.next();
        Student sName = new Student(stuName);
        System.out.println("What is the minimum passing average score: ");
        minPassAv = scan.nextInt();
        
        Student stu = new Student();
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a quiz score: ");
            currentScore = scan.nextInt();
            
            stu.addQuiz(currentScore);
            monStu.setMinPassingAvg(currentScore);
            
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter any more scores?: (Y for yes, N for no)");
            scan.nextLine();
            repeat = scan.nextLine();
            
        }while(repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));   
        
        String studName = stu.getName();
        double totalScore = stu.getTotalScore();
        double avgScore = stu.getAverageScore();
        boolean offProb = monStu.isOffProbation();
        
        System.out.println(studName + "'s Total Score is: " + totalScore);
        System.out.println(studName + "'s Average Score is: " + avgScore);
        System.out.println("Is " + studName + "off academic probation?: " + offProb);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating 2 objects? One for Student and the other for MonitoredStudent?
You are essentialy, populating the Student object but fetching the probation status from MonitoredSudent, which has never been populated.

Comment: `monStu` is already a student - you created an _IS A_ relationship with the use of `extends`. But, you go on to create two other Student objects. So you have a total three separate Objects that are students. The first `stuName` is only used for the name, the second and separate is `stu` which is used for the scores, and the third `monStu` which is only used for `offProb`. Just use the `monStu` for everything and you should be fine.

Comment: Randy, when erasing all other unnecessary objects, and using monStu for every method call (don't know why it didn't occur to me that I could use monStu for method calls outside of MonitoredStudent when the whole section is on inheritance, but I digress) I'm now getting "true" for every input no matter if it fits the condition. Sample: Enter the student's name:
Bob
What is the minimum passing average score: 
70
Enter a quiz score: 
69
Would you like to enter any more scores?: (Y for yes, N for no)
N
's Total Score is: 69.0
's Average Score is: 69.0
Is off academic probation?: true

Comment: small tip: `isOffProbation` can just be implemented as `return getAverageScore() >= minPassingAvg;`. Any code of the form `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can be written as `return condition;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You main class should be something like this.

```
public class MonitoredStudentTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    MonitoredStudent monStu = new MonitoredStudent();
    String repeat = "n";
    int currentScore = 0;
    int minPassAv;

    System.out.println("Enter the student's name:");
    monStu.setName(scan.next());
    System.out.println("What is the minimum passing average score: ");
    minPassAv = scan.nextInt();

    do {
      System.out.println("Enter a quiz score: ");
      currentScore = scan.nextInt();

      monStu.addQuiz(currentScore);
      monStu.setMinPassingAvg(minPassAv);

      System.out.println("Would you like to enter any more scores?: (Y for yes, N for no)");
      scan.nextLine();
      repeat = scan.nextLine();

    } while (repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    String studName = monStu.getName();
    double totalScore = monStu.getTotalScore();
    double avgScore = monStu.getAverageScore();
    boolean offProb = monStu.isOffProbation();

    System.out.println(studName + "'s Total Score is: " + totalScore);
    System.out.println(studName + "'s Average Score is: " + avgScore);
    System.out.println("Is " + studName + "off academic probation?: " + offProb);
  }
}
```

When using inheritance you just need to create an object of child class.